# How to run batch file(having command to run .exe file) from matlab?

Tags: matlab, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a batch file from matlab. In my batch file I have the command to run the .exe file. I am using the `dos('myfile.bat')` command to run the batch file from matlab, but it is showing the error as

```
"file.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
```

What exactly is this error? And how should deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you try to run an `exe` in `MatLab`. You don't have to put it inside a batch file, you only need to call it in this way:

```
! file.exe
```

or you can setup a string and call it with `eval`:

```
command = [ '! ' filename ];
eval( command );
```

But I think the problem is that you should specify the path of `exe` (or `bat` if you like) with absolute path.

```
! D:\Development\Stuff\App.exe
```

And of course pass the arguments if required.

```
! D:\Development\Stuff\App.exe -arg1 -arg2
```